# A question about the statement of Bertini's theorem.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Bertini's theorem states that if $X$ is a closed non-singular subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$ over an algebraically closed field, there exists some hyperplane $H$ not containing $X$ such that $H\cap X$ is non-singular.

My question is this: does $H\cap X$ mean the scheme-theoretic intersection or the reduced closed sub-scheme structure on $H\cap X$?

Comment: Scheme theoretic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a community-wiki post recording the answer from the comments so that this question may be marked as answered.

> Scheme theoretic. – **Mohan**